# Issue with react native lightbox library

Tags: react-native, react-native-lightbox

I am using [react-native-lightbox](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox). I am unable to resolve two issues with the library.

1. Failed prop type: The prop 'onRequestClose' is marked as required in 'Modal' but its value is 'undefined'.How do I remove the warning?
2. How do I display image in the center? It displays on side as shown in image.

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
  export default class LightBoxImage extends Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <Lightbox underlayColor="white">
            <Image
              source={{uri: data.url}}
            />
          </Lightbox>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the `onRequestClose` warning you should provide it as a property for the component Lightbox:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
...
<Lightbox onRequestClose={_.noop}>
```

About centering the image, wrap the `Image` component inside a `View` with the following styles:

```
flex: 1,
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center'
```

And it should work